# TRIGGER SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer un trigger que en el momento de conectarse a la base de datos compruebe si el usuario system está en ese mismo momento conectado. En caso afirmativo, deberá lanzarse un error e impedir que el usuario se conecte.

Answer (score 1):

Estimando que ya tiene creado el usuario "userforquery"

```
    create profile una_conexion
    limit sessions_per_user 1;
```

Una vez realizado esto, modificar el usuario:

```
    alter user userforquery  profile una_conexion;
```

Tambien en el profile se puede definir otros limites a la session. Dejo referencia https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a67772/users.htm